# Retrieving Data From NOT Correct RSS

Tags: php, magpie

I receive an XML file with structure like this:

```
<items>
<item>
<id>...</id>
<title>...</title>
<image>...</image>
</item>
</items>
```

I normally use MagpieRss, but this feed is not a proper RSS, so $rss->items gives me an array of 10 (real number of items) empty elements.
How can I fetch the data, preferably with Magpie?
I use simpleXML now, but it is not the best option due to different formats of its output and Magpie's one. I had to  rewrite all the following code to suit to both formats.

Comment: Updated the question. Could you please give me a good documentation for magpie?

Comment: You could convert simpleXML output to a format that you need.

Comment: @PiTheNumber: this is exactly what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to fix the XML before feeding it into Magpie?

Comment: It won't help me as the structure is ok, the problem is that it is just not how rss should look like